# SQL - Converting a stored procedure that uses a table to not

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

i just got thrown into a project that uses SQL.. and this stored procedure uses tables.. i'm trying to convert it so that it doesn't use tables... but i'm so new to SQL that i'm having trouble.. can someone help or maybe guide me?  or is such a thing not possible?

i'm trying to convert it this way so i can use LINQ/Entity Framework in SQL as when i drag this stored procedure into EDML it doesn't work because it's using tables

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGame_Passer]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @GameDate varchar(8),
    @TricodeHome varchar(3)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #Passer(
        GameKey int,
        PlayerName varchar(50),
        Tricode varchar(3),
        StatString varchar(50),
        Position varchar(20),
        FantasyScore int
    )

    DECLARE @gameKey int
    SET @gameKey = (SELECT GameKey FROM Games WHERE GameDate=@GameDate
        AND TricodeHome=@TricodeHome)

    INSERT #Passer
    SELECT TOP 1 p.GameKey, p.PlayerName, p.Tricode, p.StatString, p.Position,
        (p.Yards/25 + p.Touchdowns * 6 - p.Interceptions * 2) AS FantasyScore
    FROM GamePassers AS p
    WHERE p.GameKey=@gameKey
    ORDER BY FantasyScore DESC, p.Yards DESC    

    SELECT g.*, p.PlayerName AS PasserName, p.Tricode AS PasserTricode, 
        p.StatString AS PasserStat, p.Position AS PasserPosition
    FROM Games AS g LEFT OUTER JOIN #Passer AS p ON
        g.GameKey=p.GameKey
    WHERE g.GameDate=@GameDate AND
        g.TricodeHome=@TricodeHome

    SELECT TOP 2 p.GameKey, p.PlayerName, p.Tricode, p.StatString, p.Position
    FROM GamePassers AS p
    WHERE p.GameKey=@gameKey
    ORDER BY p.Yards DESC   

    DROP TABLE #Passer
END
```

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Googling tells me you might want table variables: http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx

Comment: (Honestly, whoever assigned you this work should've guided you through this, I stumbled upon that by accident and I'm going off a hunch that that's what they meant.)

Comment: matthew just kinda in over my head right now and i modified the code i posted to the most simplest version (the original had like 6 tables.. so right now i made it into just this 1 table for now so i can work on it.. unfortunately it's as far as i got)

Comment: kk i'll look into that millimoose.  but unfortunately this is at work.. just one of those things where "i gotta get it done" whether i know it or not

Comment: @Matthew Is that link unbanned now? Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any SQL statement can be turned into a subquery instead of being a table.  Where you refer to #passer, you can just refer to the sql statement used to insert rows into #passer.

This statement:

```
SELECT g.*, p.PlayerName AS PasserName, p.Tricode AS PasserTricode, 
    p.StatString AS PasserStat, p.Position AS PasserPosition
FROM Games AS g LEFT OUTER JOIN #Passer AS p ON
    g.GameKey=p.GameKey
WHERE g.GameDate=@GameDate AND
    g.TricodeHome=@TricodeHome
```

replace #passer with the sql code used to populate #passer.

```
SELECT g.*, p.PlayerName AS PasserName, p.Tricode AS PasserTricode, 
    p.StatString AS PasserStat, p.Postion AS PasserPosition
FROM Games AS g LEFT OUTER JOIN    
        ( SELECT TOP 1 p.GameKey, p.PlayerName, p.Tricode, p.StatString, p.Position,
        (p.Yards/25 + p.Touchdowns * 6 - p.Interceptions * 2) AS FantasyScore
        FROM GamePassers AS p
        WHERE p.GameKey=@gameKey)  AS p ON
         g.GameKey=p.GameKey
        WHERE g.GameDate=@GameDate AND
        g.TricodeHome=@TricodeHome
```

Hopefully I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: oh god i hope this works.  will let you know, thank you so much for this help regardless if that's what i needed or not, appreciate it

Comment: will come back to this as i have a meeting, but promise i'll come back.  ty so much

Comment: The one thing to be wary of here...You appear to be using an order by statement to return 'top 1' in what is now the subquery.  Subqueries cannot have the order by clause, so you may need to reword the 'top 1' logic as well.